# Creating a jqGrid builder object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object, `WorkflowGridBuilder`, which is responsible for building a `jqGrid` object and decorating it appropriately based on the type of grid being built.

Here is my builder:

```
var WorkflowGridBuilder;

$(WorkflowGridBuilder = function () {
    'use strict';

    function buildGrid(data) {
        var grid = $('#' + data.gridElementID);
        var gridPager = $('#' + data.gridPagerElementID);

        grid.jqGrid(
            $.extend({
                datatype: 'local',
                gridview: true,
                height: 'auto',
                pager: gridPager,
                viewrecords: true,
                multiselect: true,
                minHeight: 350,
                caption: data.defaultCaption,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                loadError: function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                },
                ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
                    $(this).trigger('gridOnDblClickRow', $(this).getRowData(rowid));
                }
            }, data)
        );

        grid.getSelectedRows = function () {
            var selectedRows = [];

            $.each(grid.getGridParam('selarrrow'), function () {
                selectedRows.push(grid.getRowData(this));
            });

            return selectedRows;
        };

        return grid;
    }

    return {
        buildOrdersGrid: function () {
            var ordersGrid = buildGrid({
                gridElementID: 'OrdersGrid',
                gridPagerElementID: 'OrdersGridPager',
                colNames: ['Order ID', 'Project Subcode', 'Incident Number', 'Cost Center', 'Name', 'Customer'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'ID', hidden: true },
                    { name: 'ProjectSubcode' },
                    { name: 'IncidentNumber' },
                    { name: 'CostCenter' },
                    { name: 'Name' },
                    { name: 'Customer' }
                ],
                defaultCaption: 'Orders: no filter applied'
            });
            return ordersGrid;
        },

        buildTaskGrid: function () {
            var tasksGrid = buildGrid({
                gridElementID: 'TasksGrid',
                gridPagerElementID: 'TasksGridPager',
                colNames: ['Order', 'Task ID', 'Task #', 'Type', 'Status', 'Assignee', 'Current Location', 'Dest Location', 'Change No', 'Net Patched', 'SAN Patched'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Order' },
                    { name: 'ID', hidden: true },
                    { name: 'TaskNo' },
                    { name: 'Type' },
                    { name: 'Status' },
                    { name: 'Assignee' },
                    { name: 'CurrentLocation' },
                    { name: 'DestLocation' },
                    { name: 'ChangeNo' },
                    { name: 'NetPatched' },
                    { name: 'SANPatched' }
                ],
                defaultCaption: 'Tasks: no filter applied',
                //Decorate with task-specific properties.
                grouping: true,
                groupingView: {
                    groupField: ['Order'],
                    groupColumnShow: [false]
                }
            });

            return tasksGrid;
        }
    };
} ());
```

Each of the built objects are stored in their own, respective object. I noticed that the methods I am defining in these objects are being duplicated. I'm not sure if these methods can (or should) be moved down to the builder, or possibly out to another object altogether.

```
function TasksGrid() {
    'use strict';
    var tasksGrid = WorkflowGridBuilder.buildTaskGrid();

    //Public methods:
    return {
        setWidth: function (width) {
            tasksGrid.setGridWidth(width, true);
        },
        reload: function (queueName, queueID) {
            tasksGrid.clearGridData();
            tasksGrid.setCaption(tasksGrid.defaultCaption);
            $('#load_' + tasksGrid.prop('id')).show();

            $.getJSON('../../csweb/Orders/GetTasks/?queueID=' + queueID, function (data) {
                tasksGrid.setGridParam({
                    data: data
                }).trigger('reloadGrid');

                tasksGrid.setCaption(queueName + ' Tasks');
            });
        },
        getSelectedTasks: tasksGrid.getSelectedRows,
        setEventListener: function (eventName, onEvent) {
            tasksGrid.bind(eventName, onEvent);
        }
    };
};

function OrdersGrid() {
    'use strict';
    var ordersGrid = WorkflowGridBuilder.buildOrdersGrid();

    //Public methods:
    return {
        setWidth: function (width) {
            ordersGrid.setGridWidth(width, true);
        },
        reload: function (queueName, queueID) {
            ordersGrid.clearGridData();
            ordersGrid.setCaption(ordersGrid.defaultCaption);
            $('#load_' + ordersGrid.prop('id')).show();

            $.getJSON('../../csweb/Orders/GetOrders/?queueID=' + queueID, function (data) {
                ordersGrid.setGridParam({
                    data: data
                }).trigger('reloadGrid');

                ordersGrid.setCaption(queueName + ' Orders');
            });
        },
        getSelectedOrders: ordersGrid.getSelectedRows,
        setEventListener: function (eventName, onEvent) {
            ordersGrid.bind(eventName, onEvent);
        }
    };
};
```

As you can see, TasksGrid and OrdersGrid both return the same methods.

I started by trying to move the 'setWidth' function down to WorkflowGridBuilder:

```
//WorkflowGridBuilder's return:
return {
    gridMethods: {
        setWidth: function (width) {
            //grid.setGridWidth(width, true);
      }
    },
    buildOrdersGrid: ...
}
```

At this point I realized that my code would not work. There is no 'grid' object to call `setGridWidth` on. This object will not exist until one of my builder methods is called.

Does this mean that `TasksGrid` and `OrdersGrid` are forced to repeat their public methods in the way seen above? I don't see any good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the prototype design pattern.

```
function GridFactory(name, queueUrl, obj) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gridObj = obj;
    this.url = {
        queue : queueUrl
    };
};
GridFactory.prototype.setWidth = function(width){
    this.gridObj.setGridWidth(width, true);
};
GridFactory.prototype.setEventListener = function (eventName, onEvent) {
    this.gridObj.bind(eventName, onEvent);
};
GridFactory.prototype.reload = function (queueName, queueID) {
    this.gridObj.clearGridData();
    this.gridObj.setCaption(this.gridObj.defaultCaption);
    $('#load_' + this.gridObj.prop('id')).show();

    $.getJSON(this.url.queue + queueID, function (data) {
        this.gridObj.setGridParam({
            data : data
        }).trigger('reloadGrid');

        this.gridObj.setCaption(queueName + ' ' + this.name);
    });
};
GridFactory.prototype.getSelectedRows = function(){
    return this.gridObj.getSelectedRows;
};

function TasksGrid() {
    return new GridFactory('Task', 
        '../../csweb/Orders/GetTasks/?queueID=', 
        WorkflowGridBuilder.buildTaskGrid()
    );
}

function OrdersGrid() {
    return new GridFactory('Orders', 
        '../../csweb/Orders/GetOrders/?queueID=', 
        WorkflowGridBuilder.buildOrdersGrid()
    );
}
```